# Node.js async function without callback blocks main thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, blocking

So I noticed after making some recent changes to my Node.js app, the server stops responding after some requests. I think I've nailed down the culprit but want to confirm.

So I have a function which removes a file from the filesystem after use, I don't really care about the response from the file deletion so I just ignore it.

So lets say I have this function:

```
removeFileAtPath(filePath, callback) {
  fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
    if (callback) {
      return callback(err)
    }
  });
}
```

This gets called from a middleware function, so normally would be called like this:

```
uploadFile(req, res, next) {
  // Do something
  removeFileAtPath(path, (error) => {
     if (error) { /* handle error */ }
     res.send(someResponse)
  });
}
```

But since I don't care about the function response, I call the `removeFileAtPath` function like this:

```
uploadFile(req, res, next) {
  // Do something
  removeFileAtPath(path);    // No callback passed in here
  res.send(someResponse);
}
```

Will something like this block the main loop or is my issue likely somewhere else?

Comment: Nope it wont block the loop

Comment: Everything seams to be OK. I think the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: You're right, the no callback thing wasn't the cause. I was apparently leaking a database connection in the `// Do something` part, which I found hangs the entire node process if the database connection pool gets exhausted. More on how I detected this in this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42319762/379226

Answer (score 0):

Try to call next() function at the end of your middleware

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't block - if you mean the main thread and the event loop - `fs.unlinkSync` would block in that sense.

But you still need to make sure that you return the response **or** call the next middleware - otherwise you will "block" the request from being served even though the thread and event loop will not be blocked in the usual sense and your server will still be able to handle other requests and events.