# Node.js: How to determine cause of server hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently started noticing my Node.js app server hanging after a number of requests. After more investigation I narrowed it down to a specific endpoint. After about 30 hits on this endpoint, the server just stops responding and requests start timing out.

In summary, on each request the clients upload a file, server does some preliminary checks, creates a new processing job, puts that on a queue, using [bull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull), and returns a response to the client. The server then continues to process the job on the queue. The job process involves retrieving job data from a `Redis` database, clients opening WebSocket connections to check on job status, and server writing to the database once job is complete. I understand any one of those things could be causing the hang up.

There are no errors or exceptions being thrown or logged. All I see is requests start to time out. I am using node-inspector to try to figure out what is causing the hang ups but not sure what to look for.

My question is, is there a way to determine the root cause of hang up, using a debugger or some other means, to figure out too many `ABC` instances have been created, or too many `XYZ` connections are open.

Answer (score 4):

In this case it was not actually a Node.js specific issue. I was leaking a database connection in one code path. I learned the hard way, if you exhaust database connections, your Node server will stop responding. Requests just seem to hang.

A good way to track this down, on Postgres at least is by running the query:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

Which lists all the open database connections, as well as which query was last run on that connection. Then you can check your code for where that query is called, which is super helpful in tracking down leaks.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what does "I was leaking a database connection" mean?

Comment: I'm using a database connection pool, which keeps a pool of connections I can use anytime I need one. Anytime I retrieve a connection from the pool, run my query, I'm supposed to mark it is done and return the connection to the poo for future use. Failure to do so will result in the connection not being returned to the pool, meaning I'll run out of connections eventually, which cause the app to hang. I'm using this pooling library: https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your node server debugging can be done using the following tools.

*Nodemon* is an excellent tool to do debugging because it will display errors just like node but it will also attempt to restart your server based on new changes; removing a lot of the stop/start hastle. 
https://nodemon.io/

Finally I would recommend *Postman*.  Postman lets you manually send in requests to your server, and will help you narrow your search. 
https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already do use nodemon and postman. Postman did help me isolate the

Answer (score 0):

Related to OP's issue and solution from my experience:

If you are using the **`mysql`** library and get a specific connection `connection.getConnection(...)` you need to remember to release it afterwards `connection.release();`

Otherwise your pool will run out of connections and your process will hang.